# Does EntityFramework Core support Eager Loading of entities?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using EntityFramework Core in a .NetCoreApp with Sqlite DB.
I am trying to get "Eager Loading" to work

Consider the following snippet:

```
var blog2 = context.Blogs
    .Where(b => b.Name == "Foo")
    .Include("Posts")
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

The issue is with the .Include().
I do not see Include() in my intellisense in VS 2019.

Am I missing a namespace or package reference?

Is "Eager Loading" not supported in EntityFramework Core?

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` and `System.Linq` may be a missing namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Bad syntax... try:

```
var blog2 = context.Blogs
.Where(b => b.Name == "Foo")
.Include(b => b.Posts)
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager

**Edit**

You can auto import usings by setting cursor over `Include()` and pressing `Ctrl+.`. In your case, you might be missing
`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`
at the top of your .cs file.

Also note that you'll need to add EFCore package for SQLite
[image]